# ¿Cómo traducir "ilunga" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

De acuerdo con Wikipedia, [**ilunga**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilunga_(palabra)) es una palabra de la lengua bantú,  que no tiene traducción exacta a otro idioma, pero cuya traducción aproximada es:

> El grado moral de una persona que está lista para perdonar y olvidar una primera ofensa, tolerarla una segunda vez, pero nunca perdonar ni tolerar una tercera.

¿Alguna idea de una traducción / adaptación un poco más concisa?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de traducción esperas? ¿Algo en una palabra o simplemente la expresión más concisa (con menos palabras) que podamos pensar?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: Una expresión más concisa que la parrafada que ofrece Wikipedia (idealmente una sola palabra, pero dudo que exista)

Comment: Si mil lingüistas (según Wikipedia) han determinado que es la palabra mas difícil de traducir dudo que encontremos nosotros una definición mejor, teniendo en cuenta que no sabemos el idioma, solo podemos hacer conjeturas a partir de traducciones hechas por otros.

Comment: @blonfu ¿qué tal en cuatro palabras? :-) Esto es como un [tag:translation-golf] pero con definiciones de palabras sueltas y contando palabras en vez de letras.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Sí, puede verse así pero aquí no traducimos sino que suponemos que esa traducción es correcta, partiendo de ahí sí se puede sacar algo. Veo que has contestado encontrando una palabra bastante buena.

Comment: @blonfu por supuesto, yo he dado por válida la traducción/interpretación que ofrecen las Wikipedias en español e inglés. Si tengo que plantearme la validez de esa interpretación, aviados vamos.

Comment: +1. Como pregunta me parece interesante. Me llama la atención esa diferenciación de primera/segunda/tercera y la actuación en cada caso. El problema es que al hilar tan fino hay menos posibilidades de que se recoja algo tan específico con un solo término o una expresión en lugar de una explicación. Espero que esto no degenere en preguntas tipo "Cómo se llama al estado de embriaguez de un poeta manco de la mano *izquierda* por el que alucina ver la figura de un dragón de *seis* patas recortada contra la luna de *cuarto creciente* en una noche *fresca* de *marzo* en fecha *impar* entre 2-3 am?"

Comment: @Diego: Suponte que en chino (por ejemplo) tuvieran la palabra 腫凛費卓 para designar un estado como el que describes, porque es algo recurrente en su literatura. ¿No sería Interesante intentar traducirlo?

Comment: Luis, como ejercicio o pasatiempo (tipo _translation-golf_ como menciona Carlos en los comentarios), sí. Siempre vamos a aprender algo. La utilidad o sentido practico ya habría que cuestionarlo. No lo veo distinto a traducir un anglicismo, pero como digo, mi ejemplo es exagerado a propósito. Creo que la pregunta actual añade valor al sitio. Simplemente espero que este modelo de pregunta no degenere al absurdo.

Comment: @Diego y porque se te acabaron los caracteres del comentario, que si no aún seguías escribiendo la definición... Yo no creo que este tipo de preguntas vaya a degenerar, tampoco hay palabras con tanto significado. En el chat ha salido el caso de [Mamihlapinatapai](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamihlapinatapai), que es la palabra más concisa del mundo, y su definición es "Una mirada entre dos personas, cada una de las cuales espera que la otra comience una acción que ambas desean pero que ninguna se anima a iniciar". No es tan larga como tu definición inventada, como ves.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, cierto, pero mi preocupación es que esto degenere de forma **artificial**. Todas estas propuestas son de otros idiomas. Incluso, si como dice Luis, ese caso _tan_ específico fuese parte de una cultura lo entendería. Lo que digo es que si llega el día en que de forma artificial vamos a ir a por casos muy específicos que no son de otros idiomas, lo mismo podría discutirse en meta un juego alternativo al T-golf.

Comment: Como pregunta, pues sí, me parece totalmente artificial.  A mí me gustan las preguntas estilo "necesito tal término para explicar a mi cuñado cómo usar mi lavadora de ropa."  Bueno, también me gustan los juegos como translation-golf... pero eso se declara explícitamente como juego.  Esta pregunta no.  Es una pregunta que surge del blogoesfera.  (¿Blogosfera?)  Mi voto es por cerrar.  (Véase https://robertstevenson.wordpress.com/2008/07/19/the-worlds-most-difficult-word-to-translate-loses-much-in-translation/, ...

Comment: https://www.newyorker.com/tech/elements/the-glossary-of-happiness, http://www.wordfocus.com/ilunga.html, etc.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't honestly declare the idle intellectual curiosity that sparked the question, and doesn't lay out the history of the internet's fascination with this word.  On the other hand if you want to create a new type of game question, please begin the process at Meta.

Answer (score 5):

Si buscamos en la Wikipedia en inglés, la definición habla simplemente de una "persona que ..." y no del "grado moral de una persona que ...". Por tanto, eliminemos lo del "grado moral" de la ecuación y veamos qué nos queda.

En español tenemos:

> [**indulgente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LRjaY36)
>
> Del lat. *indulgens, -entis*.
>
> 1. adj. Inclinado a perdonar y disimular los yerros o a conceder gracias.

Esta palabra puede usarse para la parte de perdonar (el primer fallo) y tolerar (el segundo), ya que habla de la capacidad para perdonar y disimular los yerros. Faltaría la última parte, la de "no perdonar una tercera". Para eso habrá que recurrir a algún modificador aparte. Propongo las siguientes opciones:

- Indulgente pero no mucho.
- Indulgente pero sin pasarse.
- Moderadamente indulgente.

Aunque creo que la que podría respetar más el concepto original es:

- **Indulgente hasta la tercera.**

Entendiéndose "la tercera" como "la tercera vez que le falles a esa persona" o, siguiendo la definición, "el tercer yerro".