# ¿Punto al final de los elementos de una lista?

Tags: puntuación

Viendo las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22306/c%C3%B3mo-traducir-ilunga-al-espa%C3%B1ol), he observado que en una de ellas aparece una lista de opciones (la negrita es mía):

- Indulgente pero no mucho **.**
- Indulgente pero sin pasarse **.**
- Moderadamente indulgente **.**

Me ha llamado la atención que cada una de ellas termina con un **punto y aparte**, y no sé si es correcto, al no ser oraciones. He consultado el [**DPD**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=punto), pero no acabo de aclararme.

¿Es correcto / obligatorio / opcional ese uso del punto?

Comment: Pienso que si es correcto. En la referencia del DPD aparece lo siguiente: _"El punto y aparte es, pues, el que separa dos párrafos distintos, que suelen desarrollar, dentro de la unidad del texto, ideas o contenidos diferentes."_

Comment: @DGaleano: efectivamente, pero justo antes indica "*Si se escribe al final de un párrafo y el enunciado siguiente inicia un párrafo nuevo, se denomina punto y aparte ... La primera línea de cada párrafo debe tener un margen mayor que el resto de las líneas que lo componen, es decir, ha de quedar sangrada.*" No tengo claro si los elementos de esa lista son **enunciados** y caso de que sea así, ¿no debería cada línea **tener un márgen mayor**?

Comment: Por alusiones, comentar que [esta otra respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22292/12637) a otra pregunta uso comas al final de cada elemento de lista, incluso poniendo un "y" antes del último.

Answer (score 3):

Fundéu tiene lo siguiente en [*enumeraciones con viñetas (puntuación)*](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/puntuacion-en-enumeraciones-con-vinetas-10941/):

> Pregunta: ¿Debe comenzar siempre en mayúscula? ¿Es correcto utilizar punto y coma o punto?
> Respuesta: Las dos puntuaciones son válidas, pero las mayúsculas han de ser las que corresponden a la puntuación elegida (minúsculas con punto y coma, mayúsculas con punto).

Y hacen luego referencia a [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Enumeraci%C3%B3n) donde dice:

> A la hora de montar listas, hay que tener en cuenta varios puntos:
>
> - la continuidad y coherencia gramatical;
> - la puntuación tras la introducción (punto, dos puntos o nada);
> - la puntuación tras los elementos (coma, punto y coma, punto o nada);
> - la mayúscula o la minúscula al comienzo de cada ítem (que está relacionado con la puntuación).

Donde ellos mismos usan *punto y coma* pero el tercer párrafo establece que puede también ser *punto* o puede no haber nada.

Nótese que el ejemplo usa *punto y coma* para separar los elementos de la lista, pero el último elemento termina en *punto y aparte*.

En el caso presente, [Carlos escribe](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22307/1674) correctamente la lista con *puntos y aparte* y mayúsculas iniciales pero luego de revisar las referencias pienso que ahora prefiero usar *punto y coma* sobre el uso del *punto aparte*.

Answer (score 2):

Viendo la pregunta (en inglés) que enlaza @walen en un comentario, sobre el uso de mayúsculas en las listas: [How should I capitalize questions in a bullet list?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21929/how-should-i-capitalize-questions-in-a-bullet-list/21932#21932), veo que atinadamente señala que en una de las respuestas no solo se responde  a la pregunta allí planteada, sino también a la planteada aquí. Copio y extraigo de la respuesta de @fedorqui a quien se debe todo el mérito:

> a) Cuando los elementos que se relacionan son simples, es decir, están constituidos por una palabra o por un grupo sintáctico breve, hay dos opciones. Cabe cerrar cada uno de los conceptos con coma, excepto el último, que se cerrará con punto. Es igualmente válido prescindir de los signos de puntuación...
>
> b) Cuando los elementos de la lista son más complejos -bien por su mayor extensión, bien por presentar puntuación interna-, es preferible el uso del punto y coma....
>
> c) Cuando la relación se compone de enunciados completos, la práctica más recomendable es cerrar cada miembro de la enumeración con punto.

Parece, por tanto, que la respuesta correcta a la pregunta concreta que planteo (caso de @fedorqui) es que no es correcta la utilización de un punto en esos casos.

Comment: recupero esta respuesta para que sea más evidente la respuesta y no se tenga que ir a la parte exacta de la respuesta a la otra pregunta.

Comment: La duda que queda es si aplican los numerales a) o b) de la respuesta de @fedorqui o el numeral c) _enunciados completos_. Yo me inclino por ésta última.